# dartdoc is trying to parse all the source files when is called inside a Flutter App folder

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

I am trying to generate the documentation for a Flutter App with [dartdoc](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc). For that I go inside the Flutter App folder:

```
cd path/to/app
```

After that I call in the console:

```
dartdoc
```

And the first results printed in the console tell me that dartdoc is parsing the files of my App, but then is trying to parse the Flutter source files (like `/opt/Flutter/bin...`).
Is there any way to only parse the folder of my app?

Comment: I've read the help and tried some of the flags, but I cannot get the expected result

Comment: Seems to be a known issue https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/issues/1949

Answer (score 0):

This line of code saved me a lot of time.

```
dartdoc --exclude 'dart:ui,dart:async,dart:collection,dart:convert,dart:core,dart:developer,dart:math,dart:typed_data,dart:ffi,dart:io,dart:isolate,dart:html,dart:js,dart:js_util'
```